# Why can't "asof" join be both "nearest" and "strict"?

Tags: empirical-lang

Going through the [demo](https://www.empirical-soft.com/demo.html), why does Empirical prohibit the following?

```
>>> join trades, events on symbol asof timestamp nearest strict
Error: join 'asof' cannot be both 'nearest' and 'strict'
```

Is there a way to match a timestamp that is closest but not exact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not permitted because the matched row could be out of order. Imagine this setup:

```
data LeftItem: time: Time, code1: Char end
data RightItem: time: Time, code2: Char end
let left = !LeftItem([Time("09:30"), Time("09:31")], ['A', 'B'])
let right = !RightItem([Time("09:30"), Time("09:31")], ['a', 'b'])
```

We now have these Dataframes:

```
>>> left
     time code1
 09:30:00     A
 09:31:00     B

>>> right
     time code2
 09:30:00     a
 09:31:00     b
```

If there were a "nearest strict", then the result would be

```
     time code1 code2
 09:30:00     A     b
 09:31:00     B     a
```

It's *correct* in the sense that we have the closest row that isn't exact, but it doesn't make any sense. We expect time to monotonically increase, so the matched rows should never be in reverse order.

So the most sensible approach is to allow "strict" on "backward" and "forward" directions, but not on "nearest".